# SQL Connection close in c# timeout

Tags: c#, sql-server, timeout, sqlconnection

I am attempting a simple close of a SQL connection in C# using `SqlConnection.Close()` (I've also tried `SqlConnection.Dispose()` with the same results) but the close is hanging until it times out. After the timeout, the connection actually does close.

Any ideas? I've seen opens timeout for various reason, but not closes.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: What happens if you wrap everything in a using clause

Comment: Using is a great idea, except I open a connection, pass that connection around and use it throughout my code in a ton of places, then close it at the end. There would be no good way to wrap all of that in a using. The code is simply cnSQL.Close() I did, just for grins, wrap the close() in a using, but it had no affect (as you might expect).